# Formatting 2D Arrays in a fortran namelist input file

Tags: fortran

Im writing a namelist input file for a Fortran code. I know that if you have a 1D array, you can populate a range of elements by,

```
&namelist
array(10) = 0, 1, 2, ......., n
&END
```

is the equivalent of

```
&namelist
array(10) = 0
array(11) = 1
array(12) = 2
...
array(10 + n) = n
&END
```

I need to now write a 2d array. I want to do the shortest equivalent to

```
&namelist
array2d(1,1) = 1
array2d(1,2) = 2
&END
```

Can I write that as

```
&namelist
array2d(1) = 1, 2
&END
```

or do I need to write this as

```
&namelist
array2d(1,1) = 1, 2
&END
```

Comment: If you're writing it why don't you try the above and find out?

Comment: Because I'm not writing the file directly. I'm writing a LabView client that talks to a Java server that formats the namelist input to a Fortran code. So in short it's simpler to ask now than try to debug this latter.

Comment: Until you figure it all out, you could write a 1D array, read it in Fortran, and reshape it into 2D.

Comment: The fortran code isn't mine and I don't have the ability to modify it.

Comment: How does the namelist look like in the program then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wow, thanks for the question -- never heard of namelists before :) This is useful!! :) After a little testing, older gfortran versions have a problem with this. Let's say you have

```
program nltest
  implicit none
  integer :: a(3,3)
  namelist /mylist/ a
  a = 0
  open(7, file='nlinput.txt')
  read(7, nml = mylist)
  write(*,*) a
end program nltest
```

- read a whole array, `a=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` : this works fine and reads a(1,1), a(2,1), ... as expected regardless of the compiler.
- read an array slice, e.g. `a(2,:)=1,2,3` : this works fine with ifort and gfortran 4.6.1, but with gfortran 4.3 it does not.

So to do what you want you should be able to write `array2d(1,:) = 1,2` if the code is compiled with a recent compiler.